# How to display data from sqlite in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, sqlite, uitableview

I am noob in sqlite on iphone and I learned a few days. I searched on internet and this site and so confused about sqlite and to use of it.
I have one json url that has many value. I want to receive and parse one specific value and save in sqlite and read from sqlite in UITableView.

I parses json and save it in sqlite DB with specific Query but I dont know about retrieving data and displaying it. 
please tell me this with code.
Sorry if my English not good.

Comment: please no negative rating ... guide me!!!

Comment: Native sqlite api is not very developer friendly, you can try [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). You can find a nice tutorial [here](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/836_Persisting_iOS_Application_Data_in_SQLite_Database_Using_FMDB.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through my answer here : -

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16322989/edit

Hope it will help you

for display array value use this code :

```
Now in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    //Add the Bg Image to the cell
     //Add the Label
     UILabel *cellTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 7, 300, 30)];
     [cellTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
     [cellTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
     [cellTitle setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
     [cellTitle setText:[[array objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"]];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:cellTitle];
     return  cell;

   }
```

also in the numberOfRowsInSection:

```
   -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section   
   {
       return [array count];
   }
```

Comment: my friend how I show value in array in tableview?

Comment: I updated my code , hope it resolved your problem .

Answer (score 0):

here is a tutorial for sqlite check it.this made a costume class for sqlite this help you .

http://www.xprogress.com/post-38-new-sqlite3-handling-library-for-iphones-and-cocoa-now-under-development/

Comment: The link appears to be very old.

Comment: this is work fine ... i am also use this file for sqlite

Comment: Just wanted to confirm, if you have really tried it.

Comment: Ya . I am use this file in my last project this still working.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code inside the method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [ArrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

this may help you